# .NET 4.0 WebServices and IPv6

Tags: .net, web-services, iis, iis-7

I have a WebService deployed into IIS 7.0.
If I access that WebService using the IPv4 binding it works and I can see the WSDL. However, accessing it using the IPv6 binding return me a System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

```
[UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.]
   System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind) +7955439
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerType..ctor(Type type, String uri) +75
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerProtocol.Initialize() +322
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing) +160

[InvalidOperationException: Unable to handle request.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing) +800924
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +302

[InvalidOperationException: Failed to handle request.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +731240
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +308
   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +89
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +608
   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +193
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +371
```

If I access a normal ASP page it works.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Upgrading the .Net Framework to 4.6

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46854

---

We faced the same issue where we could use 'IPv6 url' to access till the web service directory level but threw an exception when accessing .asmx

http:// [fe11::b111:327b:28ef:ee9e]/WebServicePath                 //Works

http:// [fe11::b111:327b:28ef:ee9e]/WebServicePath/MyService.asmx  //Exception thrown

This is now fixed after upgrading .net framework 4.5.1 to 4.6(RC)